# Chef require gems from recipe gives LoadError

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am using the [database cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database) on an ubuntu virtual server.

When trying to create a postgresql database the script throws a `LoadError: cannot load such file -- pg`

I've already installed `pg` by doing:

```
chef_gem 'pg' do
  action :install
end
```

But the chef ruby binary can't find the gems I install through chef_gem. This happens with any gem I install.

How can I import the gems? Am I missing something?

I am running:
Chef Client, version 11.8.2
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to include the [`database::postgresql`](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database/blob/master/recipes/postgresql.rb) recipe into your runlist. It in turn uses the [`postgresql::ruby`](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/postgresql/blob/master/recipes/ruby.rb) recipe to install the `pg` gem into your Omnibus Ruby.

As you can see in the latter recipe, the actual installation can be a bit complicated depending on the environment. But as that is taken care of already, it shouldn't be a problem here.

Comment: In my case, the error was caused by the rvm cookbook, its gem_package recipe, once it is included `chef_gem` starts behaving just like `gem_package` and installs gems to a wrong place so Chef doesn't see them.

Answer (score 0):

You might need some of the packages

```
libxml2-devel
libxslt
libxslt-devel
```

Installing these yum packages helped me when I had got a similar error.